# Editing a particular column in html table

Tags: php, html, css

I have a html table which diplays some record.If I want to a edit particular column field for a record.How can I do that?

I want to make table editable from front end. I am using php as backend

Comment: Do you want to make the table editable from the front end or how ? Please explain.

Comment: want to make it editable from front end

Comment: Are you retrieving the data from query (db) and want the editing affects (updates) the data in the table or just want it for instance.

Comment: I am retrieving data from db and yes want the editing effects in db as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contenteditable` attribute of `html5` and use change of the cell content call the update query.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('blur','p',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('changed..!');
    /*$.ajax(
      AJAX page which updates the cell content with the column name specified. Send the value and column name to the page and run the update query with it on the table. 
    );*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text. On change of the content do call an ajax and update the db.</p>

</body>
</html>
```